# Can one define one's own words and phrases in Microsoft Windows 11's voice access?

Tags: windows-11, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

From https://beebom.com/what-is-voice-access-windows-11-how-use/:

> Voice access is a new Windows 11 accessibility feature that makes it easier to control your Windows 11 PC using only your voice.

Can one define one's own words and phrases in Microsoft Windows 11's voice access? (i.e., add a word or a phrase to the dictionary, such as "Stack Exchange")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The personal dictionary only impacts typing suggestions and handwriting recognition, according to these screenshots from https://www.thewindowsclub.com/view-customize-and-clear-your-personal-dictionary-in-windows-11:

[image]

[image]